# Prove $|a − x| < |a − b|$

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry

Prove that if $a, b, c$ are distinct points of $\mathbb R^d$
such that $∠abc < π/2$, then there is a $x$ on the open segment $(b, c)$ with $|a − x| < |a − b|$.

I tried to take these points as three vertices of an acute-angled triangle such that $∠abc < \pi/2$, and tried to take the property of sum of two sides is greater than the third side i.e. $ab +bc > ac$ then I draw a line from the point $a$ which intersect $bc$ at $x$. Then again I took the sum of two sides property such that $ab + ax > bx$ and after trying all the possibilities I am not unable to prove the above.

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that there exist some 'x' on line segment $bc$ such that $\|a-x\| < \|a-b\|$ ?

Comment: @Inuyashayagami yup

Comment: Just take $x$ as the projection of the line segment $ab$ on the line segment $bc$. The length of $ax$ would = $ab \cdot  \sin \theta$. Therefore $\| a-x\| < \| a-b\|$, since $\sin \theta < 1$ for $\theta<\pi /2$

Comment: @Inuyashayagami Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the triangle $abx$.  You are asking that $a$ is closer to $x$ than it is to $b$, or in other words that the line segment $ax$ is shorter than the line segment $ab$.  This would be true if and only if the measure of $\angle x$ is greater than the measure of $\angle b$.

There is certainly a point $x$ on the line segment $bc$ that satisfies that.  As noted in comments, the projection would work.  Alternatively, you could just choose an $x$ so close to $b$ that $m\angle a$ is insignificant, which would make $\angle x$ the largest angle in the triangle (since we are given that $\angle b$ is acute).

Comment: @MathewDaly Thank you for the detailed explanation. It cleared my all doubts.